# How can I use the format! macro in a no_std environment?

Tags: text, macros, formatting, rust, embedded

How could I implement the following example without using std?

```
let text = format!("example {:.1} test {:x} words {}", num1, num2, num3);
```

`text` has type `&str` and `num1`, `num2` and `num3` have any numeric type.

I've tried using `numtoa` and `itoa/dtoa` for displaying numbers but `numtoa` does not support floats and `itoa` does not support `no_std`. I feel like displaying a number in a string is fairly common and that I'm probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general, you *don't*. `format!` allocates a `String`, and a `no_std` environment doesn't have an allocator.

If you do have an allocator, you can use the [alloc crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/). This crate contains the [`format!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/macro.format.html) macro.

```
#![crate_type = "dylib"]
#![no_std]

#[macro_use]
extern crate alloc;

fn thing() {
    let text = format!("example {:.1} test {:x} words {}", 1, 2, 3);
}
```

See also:

- [How to format output to a byte array with no_std and no allocator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39488327/155423)

Comment: I'm targeting an STM32F103, will japaric's [`alloc-cortex-m`](https://github.com/japaric/alloc-cortex-m) work? Do I have any safer alternatives? Thanks so much!

Comment: @FerdiaMcKeogh I'm not sure what you mean by "safer" in this context, but it seems like a reasonable choice.

Comment: Sorry, I meant safer in terms of a stable/widely accepted method. `alloc-cortex-m` is working perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

In addition to [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50200528/1478356) you can also format strings without an allocator.

In [`core::fmt::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/fmt/trait.Write.html) you only need to implement `write_str` and then you get `write_fmt` for free.

With [`format_args!(...)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/macro.format_args.html) (same syntax as [`format!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html)) you can prepare a [`core::fmt::Arguments`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/fmt/struct.Arguments.html) value, which can be passed to [`core::fmt::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/fmt/fn.write.html).

See [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e86a41043cbcfef53047991451937d41&version=stable&mode=release):

```
#![crate_type = "dylib"]
#![no_std]

pub mod write_to {
    use core::cmp::min;
    use core::fmt;

    pub struct WriteTo<'a> {
        buffer: &'a mut [u8],
        // on write error (i.e. not enough space in buffer) this grows beyond
        // `buffer.len()`.
        used: usize,
    }

    impl<'a> WriteTo<'a> {
        pub fn new(buffer: &'a mut [u8]) -> Self {
            WriteTo { buffer, used: 0 }
        }

        pub fn as_str(self) -> Option<&'a str> {
            if self.used <= self.buffer.len() {
                // only successful concats of str - must be a valid str.
                use core::str::from_utf8_unchecked;
                Some(unsafe { from_utf8_unchecked(&self.buffer[..self.used]) })
            } else {
                None
            }
        }
    }

    impl<'a> fmt::Write for WriteTo<'a> {
        fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) -> fmt::Result {
            if self.used > self.buffer.len() {
                return Err(fmt::Error);
            }
            let remaining_buf = &mut self.buffer[self.used..];
            let raw_s = s.as_bytes();
            let write_num = min(raw_s.len(), remaining_buf.len());
            remaining_buf[..write_num].copy_from_slice(&raw_s[..write_num]);
            self.used += raw_s.len();
            if write_num < raw_s.len() {
                Err(fmt::Error)
            } else {
                Ok(())
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn show<'a>(buffer: &'a mut [u8], args: fmt::Arguments) -> Result<&'a str, fmt::Error> {
        let mut w = WriteTo::new(buffer);
        fmt::write(&mut w, args)?;
        w.as_str().ok_or(fmt::Error)
    }
}

pub fn test() {
    let mut buf = [0u8; 64];
    let _s: &str = write_to::show(
        &mut buf,
        format_args!("write some stuff {:?}: {}", "foo", 42),
    ).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Why not `let mut w = write_to::WriteTo::new(&mut buf); write!(&mut w, "café").unwrap();` ?

Comment: @Shepmaster you'll need another step to extract the result and probably a `use core::fmt::Write;` ([`write!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/macro.write.html) needs a `write_fmt` method in scope)... but yes, you can use it that way too.  Maybe a `format_buf!(&mut buf, "...", ...)` macro would be a more comfortable way - but I think that exercise can be left to the reader :)

Answer (score 4):

Write a formatter!

```rust
use core::fmt::{self, Write};
use core::str;

fn main() {
    // For LCD 160 / 8 = 20 chars
    let mut buf = [0u8; 20];
    let mut buf = ByteMutWriter::new(&mut buf[..]);
  
    buf.clear();
    write!(&mut buf, "Hello {}!", "Rust").unwrap();
    
    // buf.as_str()
}


pub struct ByteMutWriter<'a> {
    buf: &'a mut [u8],
    cursor: usize,
}

impl<'a> ByteMutWriter<'a> {
    pub fn new(buf: &'a mut [u8]) -> Self {
        ByteMutWriter { buf, cursor: 0 }
    }

    pub fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
        str::from_utf8(&self.buf[0..self.cursor]).unwrap()
    }

    #[inline]
    pub fn capacity(&self) -> usize {
        self.buf.len()
    }

    pub fn clear(&mut self) {
        self.cursor = 0;
    }

    pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.cursor
    }

    pub fn empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.cursor == 0
    }

    pub fn full(&self) -> bool {
        self.capacity() == self.cursor
    }
}

impl fmt::Write for ByteMutWriter<'_> {
    fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) -> fmt::Result {
        let cap = self.capacity();
        for (i, &b) in self.buf[self.cursor..cap]
            .iter_mut()
            .zip(s.as_bytes().iter())
        {
            *i = b;
        }
        self.cursor = usize::min(cap, self.cursor + s.as_bytes().len());
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also combine the usage of `numtoa` and `arrayvec` crates. Example:

```
#![no_std]

use numtoa::NumToA;
use arrayvec::ArrayString;

fn main() -> ! {
    let mut num_buffer = [0u8; 20];
    let mut text = ArrayString::<[_; 100]>::new();

    let num1 = 123;
    let num2 = 456;
    let num3 = 789;

    // text.clear(); (on subsequent usages)
    text.push_str("example ");
    text.push_str(num1.numtoa_str(10, &mut num_buffer));

    text.push_str(" test ");
    text.push_str(num2.numtoa_str(10, &mut num_buffer));

    text.push_str(" words ");
    text.push_str(num3.numtoa_str(10, &mut num_buffer));
}
```

Note that push_str can panic. Check out the api for `try_` -methods

And Cargo.toml

```
 [dependencies]
 arrayvec = { version = "0.5", default-features = false }
 numtoa = "0.2"
```

Answer (score 2):

I build a small crate based on Shepmaster's post. There is also a macro included that allows easy use. All this works without a heap allocator and is compatible with no_std.

```
use arrform::{arrform, ArrForm};
 
let af = arrform!(64, "write some stuff {}: {:.2}", "foo", 42.3456);
assert_eq!("write some stuff foo: 42.35", af.as_str());
```

This macro first reserves a buffer on the stack. Then it uses the struct `ArrForm` to format text and numbers. It returns an instance of `ArrForm` that allows easy access to the contained text. The macro panics if the buffer is chosen too small.

see https://github.com/Simsys/arrform or https://crates.io/crates/arrform.