# Why does fmt::Arguments as_str not work when arguments are passed?

Tags: rust, arguments

I am making a VGA print macro for my OS with `no_std`, and it is for some reason not working. I am using the [vga crate](https://github.com/rust-osdev/vga) so that I do not have to do all the VGA code myself. I have a function called `_print`:

```
use core::fmt::{Arguments, Write};
use vga::colors::Color16;
use vga::writers::{Graphics640x480x16, GraphicsWriter};

pub fn _print(args: Arguments) {
    unsafe {
        let mut i: usize = 0;
        for (_offset, character) in args.as_str().unwrap().chars().enumerate() {
            Mode.draw_character(CurrentTextX + i, CurrentTextY, character, CurrentTextColor);
            i += 8;
        }
    }
}
```

I then have a macro called `vprint!`:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! vprint {
    ($($arg:tt)*) => {
        crate::videographicsarray::_print(format_args!($($arg)*));
    };
}
```

I am not using `alloc`. I have seen code exactly like this work, but for some reason my code does not work. It displays text I enter, but if I pass any arguments, it panics. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does "it does not display any arguments I pass" imply? Does it just do nothing, does it panic, or?

Comment: It panics, sorry for not stating that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code panics because [`as_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html#method.as_str) only returns `Some`, if there is no arguments. So when you immediately `unwrap()` it will panic, for instances where you have arguments to be formatted.

> Get the formatted string, if it has no arguments to be formatted.
>
> This can be used to avoid allocations in the most trivial case.
>
> – [`std::fmt::Arguments::as_str()` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html#method.as_str)

Instead you can use [`args.to_string()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string) instead of `args.as_str().unwrap()`, to format it into a `String`. So it actually formats regardless of whether there is any arguments or not.

```rust
pub fn _print(args: Arguments) {
    unsafe {
        let mut i: usize = 0;
        for (_offset, character) in args.to_string().chars().enumerate() {
            Mode.draw_character(CurrentTextX + i, CurrentTextY, character, CurrentTextColor);
            i += 8;
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you want to avoid the needless allocations, then you could use [`unwrap_or_else()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else) and only do [`to_string()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string) if [`as_str()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html#method.as_str) returns `None`. While wrapping in [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) to avoid converting the `&str` to a `String` anyways.

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

let formatted_str = args
    .as_str()
    .map(Cow::Borrowed)
    .unwrap_or_else(|| Cow::Owned(args.to_string()));
```

---

### no_std

Since you're using `no_std` and not using the `alloc` crate. Then you can define a `u8` buffer to format into. E.g. use `let buf = [u8; N];`, where `N` is enough space for your formatted strings.

After that, you can implement your own wrapper around a `&mut [u8]` buffer, which implements the [`core::fmt::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/fmt/trait.Write.html) trait. You can use that wrapper along with with [`core::fmt::write()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/fmt/fn.write.html).

Instead of implementing your own, you can use the `struct WriteTo` from this answer: *[How can I use the format! macro in a no_std environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50201632/2470818)*

```rust
pub fn _print(args: Arguments) {
    let mut buf = [0u8; 64];
    let formatted_str: &str = write_to::show(&mut buf, args).unwrap();

    unsafe {
        let mut i: usize = 0;
        for (_offset, _character) in formatted_str.chars().enumerate() {
            Mode.draw_character(CurrentTextX + i, CurrentTextY, character, CurrentTextColor);

            i += 8;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives an error: 'no method named `to_string` found for struct `Arguments<'_>` in the current scope'

Comment: @DuelTheBearded Wait, are you using `no_std`? What about `alloc`?

Comment: I am using `no_std`, yeah.

Comment: @DuelTheBearded Could you update the question, to include your `no_std` "setup". Like which crates you're using, e.g. `core` and `alloc`?

Comment: @DuelTheBearded Didn't make it completely clear. I'd need to know if you're using `alloc`. If not, then you'd need to use something else to write to, and then instead use e.g. [`core::fmt::write(&mut writer, args)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/fmt/fn.write.html). All in all `as_str()` doesn't work, because it only returns `Some` if there are no arguments to be formatted.

Comment: @DuelTheBearded No problem, happy I could help. But in the future, probably highlight you're using `no_std`, my eyes glossed over the mention of OS :)