# Is it possible to use format! in Substrate runtime?

Tags: rust, substrate

From the [link](https://docs.rs/sp-std/2.0.0-rc3/sp_std/fmt/index.html), It seems format! can work in [Substrate](https://substrate.io/) runtime.

```
let hello_world = sp_std::fmt::format!("Hello,{}","world");
```

I want to have a variable `hello_world` and use it for latter。

But I always get an error : could not find `format` in `fmt`

I have searched for a long time, I also refs: [how to use format! in no_std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200268/how-can-i-use-the-format-macro-in-a-no-std-environment)

I have been confused for several days.

The [link](https://docs.rs/sp-std/2.0.0-rc3/sp_std/fmt/index.html) is not correct? Are there some stories behind this?

Comment: If you're trying to debug substrate then [this might help](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/debugging/).

Comment: I need a variable from the format! result.

Comment: I just tried `panic!(format!("Hi {}", 1234));` in my pallet and the tests now panic. No compile error.  
What kind of error do you get?

Comment: can not find `format!`

Comment: Maybe you can use [my pallet](https://github.com/perun-network/perun-polkadot-pallet/blob/39a6176cb4a78aac329bddd6d9dc8b307b03fea7/src/lib.rs#L225) to debug yours? It is possible to add a `format!` to the extrinsic. @gfan