# How do I print u64 to a buffer on stack in Rust

Tags: rust, format, std

I'm trying to format an `u64` to a `&str`, but without dynamically allocating any memory on heap. I want to manually declare a space on stack (e.g., `let mut buffer = [0u8; 20]` and print the `u64` to `buffer` and get a `&str` from it with some unsafe.

I tryied `write!(&mut buffer[..], "{}", i)`, but it returns a `Result<()>` and I couldn't get the length of the formatted string so as to unsafely convert it to &str.

I'm currently straightly coping the implementation of `Display for u64` from std library, is there a better way of doing so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72727634/how-to-test-result-of-corefmtdisplay-trait-implementation-in-no-std-env/.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Cursor:

```rust
use std::io::{Write, Cursor};

fn main() {
    let mut cursor = Cursor::new([0u8; 20]);
    let i = 42u64;

    write!(cursor, "{i}").unwrap();
    let pos = cursor.position();
    let buffer = cursor.into_inner();
    let text = std::str::from_utf8(&buffer[..pos as usize]).unwrap();
    println!("{text}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you and @Chayim. I did a benchmark with some methods, and here's the results. To format 4096 u64 to &str,`to_string` takes 337us, write to ArrayString takes 137us, coping code from std and suppling a `[0u8; 20]` takes 51us, coping code from std and suppling uninit takes 48us, using Cursor takes 139us (~=ArrayString). I'll go with copying code from std. Thank you guys!