# How do I make format! return a &str from a conditional expression?

Tags: string, scope, rust, lifetime, temporary

I happened upon this problem where `format!` creates a temporary value in a pattern that is not anchored to anything, as far as I understand it.

```
let x = 42;
let category = match x {
    0...9 => "Between 0 and 9",
    number @ 10 => format!("It's a {}!", number).as_str(),
    _ if x < 0 => "Negative",
    _ => "Something else",
};

println!("{}", category);
```

In this code, the type of `category` is a `&str`, which is satisfied by returning a literal like `"Between 0 and 9"`. If I want to format the matched value to a slice using `as_str()`, then I get an error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:5:24
  |
3 |     let category = match x {
  |         -------- borrow later stored here
4 |         0...9 => "Between 0 and 9",
5 |         number @ 10 => format!("It's a {}!", number).as_str(),
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                        |
  |                        creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I have done some reading, and found people with similar problems, but I couldn't seem to find any solution.

A simple workaround would be to have `category` be a `String` instead of a `&str`, but I don't like the idea of having to put `.to_string()` on the end of every literal in the pattern, as it's not as clean.

Is there a way to solve the problem, or do I just need to work around it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is 90% a duplicate of [Return local String as a slice (&str)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29428227/155423), see that for multiple other solutions.

There's one extra possibility since this is all in one function: You can declare a variable for the `String` and only set it when you need to allocate. The compiler (obliquely) suggests this:

> consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value

```
fn main() {
    let x = 42;
    let tmp;

    let category = match x {
        0...9 => "Between 0 and 9",
        number @ 10 => {
            tmp = format!("It's a {}!", number);
            &tmp
        }
        _ if x < 0 => "Negative",
        _ => "Something else",
    };

    println!("{}", category);
}
```

This is mostly the same as using a `Cow`, just handled by the compiler instead of a specific type.

See also:

- [How can I conditionally provide a default reference without performing unnecessary computation when it isn't used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58559969/155423)
- [Are polymorphic variables allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28220053/155423)

Comment: The solution only works if the match arm is a literal, otherwise rust doesn't compile since `tmp` can be assigned twice.

Comment: @PawanKumar please provide a playground example showing what you mean. The first match arm in this example does not require a string literal; that’s literally the point of the answer.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8b235475ee2cd1713e5d72e922a0352c
Matching against a fixed number works, but if it is dynamic, then the better solution would be Own the string or use a Rc.

Comment: This specific example the solution works I just wanted to point out the other solutions as well

Comment: @PawanKumar that has nothing to do with a number, [it has to do with the loop](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c69bed6ff892492df0d07b6f3806c649). The "other solutions" are already mentioned in the first line of this answer. However, [the `Cow` solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=67c0a041d424fd720db61a11695c2b1d) , as mentioned in this answer, involves less memory allocation than a required `String`.

Answer (score 3):

`format!` can't return `&str` because it will always allocate `String`. What is possible to do is to return a `&str` from a `String`, which is what you did in your code.

As the compiler hinted, the created `String` is immediately dropped after its creation because it went out of the current scope and one way around could be an external variable that is not bounded to the `match` scope. E.g.:

```
use std::fmt::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut buffer = String::with_capacity(20);
    buffer.push_str("It's a ");

    let x = 10;
    let category = match x {
        0...9 => "Between 0 and 9",
        number @ 10 => {
            write!(&mut buffer, "{}", number).unwrap();
            buffer.as_str()
        }
        _ if x < 0 => "Negative",
        _ => "Something else",
    };

    println!("{}", category);
}
```

If you want an `[no_std]` environment or don't want to do any dynamic allocation, you can take a look at this limited code snippet:

```
use core::str;

fn each_digit<F>(mut number: u32, mut f: F)
where
    F: FnMut(u8),
{
    while number > 0 {
        f((number % 10) as u8);
        number /= 10;
    }
}

fn main() {
    const BUFFER_LEN: usize = 20;
    let mut buffer = [0u8; BUFFER_LEN];

    let x = 12344329;
    let category = match x {
        0...9 => "Between 0 and 9",
        number @ 123443219 => {
            let mut idx = BUFFER_LEN;
            each_digit(number, |digit| {
                let ascii = digit + 48;
                idx -= 1;
                buffer[idx] = ascii;
            });
            str::from_utf8(&buffer[idx..BUFFER_LEN]).unwrap()
        },
        _ => "Something else",
    };

    assert_eq!("123443219", category);
}
```

Comment: You can use `write!(&mut buffer, "{}", number)` to save an allocation + copy in the first snippet, and I think it will also work under `no_std` with a fixed buffer (untested).

Comment: [How to write an integer as a string to a byte array with no_std?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39488327/155423)

Answer (score 0):

In my case [How to overcome "temporary value dropped while borrowed" when converting an i32 to &str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58490555/how-to-overcome-temporary-value-dropped-while-borrowed-when-converting-an-i32)
I could solve it by moving the call inside the branches

```
pub fn uidl(&mut self, message_number: Option<i32>) -> POP3Result {
    let command = match message_number {
        Some(_) => POP3Command::UidlOne,
        None => POP3Command::UidlAll,
    };

    match message_number {
        Some(i) => {
            // Here the value is not dropped because it is not leaving the scope
            self.execute_command(command, Some(arg.to_string().as_str()))
        }
        // Here I had to duplicate the call
        None => self.execute_command(command, None),
    }
}
```

Kind of what is suggested in the error message https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0597