# How can I conditionally provide a default reference without performing unnecessary computation when it isn't used?

Tags: rust, reference, conditional-statements, default-value

I have some variable passed into my function by reference. I don't need to mutate it or transfer ownership, I just look at its contents. If the contents are in some state, I want to replace the value with a default value.

For instance, my function accepts a `&Vec<String>` and if the `Vec` is empty, replace it with `vec!["empty"]`:

```
fn accept(mut vec: &Vec<String>) {
    if vec.len() == 0 {
        vec = &vec!["empty".to_string()];
    }
    // ... do something with `vec`, like looping over it
}
```

But this gives the error:

`````
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/lib.rs:3:16
  |
1 | fn accept(mut vec: &Vec<String>) {
  |                    - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
2 |     if vec.len() == 0 {
3 |         vec = &vec!["empty".to_string()];
  |         -------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^- temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |         |      |
  |         |      creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
  |         assignment requires that borrow lasts for `'1````
`````

Preventing the `mut` results in the same error as the previous example:

```
fn accept(input: &Vec<String>) {
    let vec = if input.len() == 0 {
        &vec!["empty".to_string()]
    } else {
        input
    };
    // ... do something with `vec`, like looping over it
}
```

The only solution I've come up with is to extract the default value outside the `if` and reference the value:

```
fn accept(input: &Vec<String>) {
    let default = vec!["empty".to_string()];
    let vec = if input.len() == 0 {
        &default
    } else {
        input
    };
    // ... do something with `vec`
}
```

This results in less clean code and also *unnecessarily doing that computation*.

I know and understand the error... you're borrowing the default value inside the body of the `if`, but that value you're borrowing from doesn't exist outside the `if`. That's not my question.

Is there any cleaner way to write out this pattern?

I don't believe this is a duplicate of [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682876/is-there-any-way-to-return-a-reference-to-a-variable-created-in-a-function) because I have a reference I'd like to use *first* if possible. I don't want to dereference the reference or `clone()` it because *that would perform unnecessary computation*.

Can I store either a value or a reference in a variable at the same time?

Comment: You're trying to paper over a misunderstanding either in your implementation or in your knowledge of Rust. If you have a method that requires pre-processing of an argument, you should be splitting this up into two calls, and inline the pre-processor, for example. This leaves your "inner" code sane, and leaves the data sanitization to the outside call.

Comment: You need to add an appropriately scoped local variable to own the `Vec` for as long as the reference lives, as in [How do I make format! return a &str from a conditional expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54222905/3650362) This is what the compiler is trying to suggest by ``consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value``.  [Here's a working version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=962fef993b0eb7138956c2d59ac9aea0). Does this help?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Ok, well in reality this "function" is a match arm part of a much larger algorithm. Only this arm does this type of sanitization to the outer variables.

Still, though. What if the "outer" code was also only provided a reference? You'd still have the same issue. I don't feel it's right to be propagating these values up the call stack to their actual creation when the condition may be dependant on local state.

Comment: I imagine the `&Vec` was only for the purpose of illustration, but if it's in your actual code, perhaps you should also read [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to create the default vector if you don't use it. You just have to ensure the declaration is done outside the `if` block.

```
fn accept(input: &Vec<String>) {
    let def;
    let vec = if input.is_empty() {
        def = vec!["empty".to_string()];
        &def
    } else {
        input
    };
    // ... do something with `vec`
}
```

Note that you don't have to build a new default vector every time you receive an empty one. You can create it the first time this happens using [lazy_static](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/) or [once_cell](https://docs.rs/once_cell/):

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

fn accept(input: &[String]) {
    let vec = if input.is_empty() {
        lazy_static! {
            static ref DEFAULT: Vec<String> = vec!["empty".to_string()];
        }
        &DEFAULT
    } else {
        input
    };
    // use vec
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be looking for [`std::borrow::Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html), depending on how you're going to use it.