# value dropped when trying to assign a slice

Tags: rust

I have a very simple case where I have some function that takes a Option<Vec>, it then needs to look at that option, and if it is a None, then have a empty byte string, but if it is a Some, then call a function that does some transofmration of it's input.

Sketched out, it looks like this:

```
pub fn transform(ad: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    ad.to_vec()

}
pub fn func(plaintext: Option<Vec<u8>>) {
    let out = "".as_bytes();
    if plaintext != None {
        let out = transform(&plaintext.unwrap());
}
}
```

Doing the unwrapping and  the if like this is really ugly though,and I would much like to do this in a safer way, maybe with pattern matching:

```
pub fn transform(ad: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    ad.to_vec()

}
pub fn func(plaintext: Option<Vec<u8>>) {

let out = match plaintext {
    Some(x) =>  &transform(&x),
    None => "".as_bytes()
};
```

}

But this gives the error:

```
    |
16 |     let out = match plaintext {
   |         --- borrow later stored here
17 |         Some(x) =>  &return_smth(&x),
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |                      |             |
   |                      |             temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                      creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

I am unsure about which value that is being talked about here. How do I call my function, and get a slice returned?

Comment: Please post the full error message. Also, please format your code. A playground link will be good.

Comment: Where is `return_smth()` defined?

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete, inconsistent, and doesn't even parse. Please edit your question to something we can understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make format! return a &str from a conditional expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54222905/how-do-i-make-format-return-a-str-from-a-conditional-expression)

Comment: IIUC, you want [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map), as in : `let out = plaintext.map (transform).unwrap_or (vec![]);`

Comment: @Jmb requires either an adaption step (`.as_deref()`) or updating `transform` tho), as `Option::<T>::map` can't cope with an `fn(&T) -> U`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am unsure about which value that is being talked about here.

The one that's returned by `transform` (or `return_smth`, or whatever else you call it): that returns a `Vec` (which is an owned value), you immediately borrow it to a slice, but you never actually store the vec, so at the end of the expression it gets dropped and you have a dangling reference.

> How do I call my function, and get a slice returned?

There are two main ways:

You don't, would be my first recommendation here. Rust has a container called [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) which stores "an owned value or a reference", which you can use like a normal reference, or convert to an owned value:

```rust
    let out = match plaintext {
        Some(x) => transform(&x).into(),
        None => b"".into(),
    };
```

The second possibility is to store the owned at the highest level you need it, then create a local borrow to *that* e.g.

```rust
    let mut _v;
    let out = match plaintext {
        Some(x) => {
            _v = transform(&x);
            &*_v
        },
        None => b"",
    };
```

This is a relatively common pattern for non-trivial code paths where you need to borrow part of the owned value rather than the entirety of it.

Incidentally,

- as you can see above Rust has bytes literals (`b""`), no need to create a string then byteify it
- as jmb commented, Rust has high-level methods for common generic tasks. Both "apply transformation to option's value" and "get value or return default" are such
- `Vec::new()` is guaranteed not to allocate, so creating an empty `Vec` (or `String`) is not a big deal.

  Hence if you don't have a very strong reason to favor a slice

  ```rust
  let out = plaintext
      .as_deref()
      .map_or_else(Vec::new, transform);
  ```

  would be perfectly fine here, or even

  ```rust
      let out = plaintext.map_or_else(Vec::new, transform);
  ```

  if you change `transform` to take and return a `Vec`.