# How do I convert u32 data to &str in an embedded platform?

Tags: rust, embedded

I want to convert u32 integer data to string in embedded Rust, but the problem is in embedded we can't use `std` code, so is there any way to do this?

```
let mut dist = ((elapsed as f32 / mono_timer.frequency().0 as f32 * 1e6) / 2.0) / 29.1;
let dist = dist as u32;
let data = String::from("data:");
data.push_str(dist);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format output to a byte array with no\_std and no allocator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488327/how-to-format-output-to-a-byte-array-with-no-std-and-no-allocator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

answer found

```
use core::fmt::Write;
use heapless::String;

fn foo() {
    let dist = 100u32;
    let mut data = String::<32>::new(); // 32 byte string buffer
    
    // `write` for `heapless::String` returns an error if the buffer is full,
    // but because the buffer here is 32 bytes large, the u32 will fit with a 
    // lot of space left. You can shorten the buffer if needed to save space.
    let _ = write!(data, "data:{dist}");
}
```

Comment: When I try to use this, `use heapless::consts::*;` returns a compile error that consts is not found. Any update to this answer as it seems like just the solution I need.