# Add number` string-like (`1+1` = `11`)

Tags: rust, rust-no-std

I'm making a calculator operating system for a proof of concept Rust OS. I've dug myself into a sort of deep hole with how I handle math, but I don't want to have to rework it all. I have 2 numbers (they are technically `f64`s but will never have a floating point) and I need to add them Javascript style (`1 + "1" = 11`). This is all in a `#![no_std]` environment so I can't use something like `format!()` or even owned `String`s as I have no allocator.

Rust isn't JS so I can't `1 + "1"` and obviously `+` is a binary operation.

Edit: I ended up using the `arrayvec` library as suggested in [How to format output to a byte array with no_std and no allocator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488327/how-to-format-output-to-a-byte-array-with-no-std-and-no-allocator)

Comment: Maybe you can use `write!` like in this question: [How to format output to a byte array with no\_std and no allocator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488327/how-to-format-output-to-a-byte-array-with-no-std-and-no-allocator)

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply the first number by 10 to the power of the number of digits of the second number. Something like this should do it:

```
fn concat(a: f64, b: f64) -> f64 {
    a * 10f64.powf(b.log10().floor() + 1.0) + b
}
```

Comment: Both `powf` and `log10` are part of the standard library.

Comment: If you're on nightly, you can opt-in to core_intrinsics: https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/core/intrinsics/index.html

Otherwise, you could always implement them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the numbers to integers, then count the number of times you need to divide `b` by 10 until you reach 0 and multiply `a` by 10 this same number of times:

```
fn concat (a: f64, b: f64) -> f64 {
    let mut a = a as u64;
    let b = b as u64;
    let mut c = b;
    while c > 0 {
        a *= 10;
        c /= 10;
    }
    (a+b) as f64
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6a3579d6fdcd6562d897dc761e64aef6)